# Convert user input string to an object to be accessed by function

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, object

I have data in the format (input):

```
doSomething({
  type: 'type',
  Unit: 'unit',
  attributes: [
    {
      attribute: 'attribute',
      value: form.first_name
    },
    {
      attribute: 'attribute2',
      value: form.family_name
    }
  ],
  groups: [
    {
      smth: 'string1',
      smth2: 'string2',
      start: timeStart.substring(0, 9)
    }
  ]
})
```

I managed to take out the doSomething part with the parenthesis as to load the function from the corresponding module with
`expression.split('({',1)[0]`

However using the loaded function with the rest, obtained with:

`expression.split(temp+'(')[1].trim().replace(/\n+/g, '').slice(0, -1)`

does not work because it should be an object and not a string. Hardcoding the data in does work as it is automatically read as an object.

My question is if there is any way of converting the string that I get from the user and convert it to an object. I have tried to convert it to a json object with JSON.parse but I get an unexpected character t at position 3. Also I have tried new Object(myString) but that did not work either.

What I would like is to have the body of the provided function as an object as if I would hard code it, so that the function can evaluate the different fields properly.
Is there any way to easily achieve that?

EDIT: the "output" would be:

```
{
  type: 'type',
  Unit: 'unit',
  attributes: [
    {
      attribute: 'attribute',
      value: form.first_name
    },
    {
      attribute: 'attribute2',
      value: form.family_name
    }
  ],
  groups: [
    {
      smth: 'string1',
      smth2: 'string2',
      start: timeStart.substring(0, 9)
    }
  ]
}
```

as an object. This is the critical part because I have this already but as a string. However the function that uses this, is expecting an object. Like previously mentioned, hard coding this would work, as it is read as an object, but I am getting the input mentioned above as a string from the user.

Comment: can you show the expected result you want to achive

Comment: It's unclear what your `input` is and what the `output` should be.

Comment: @PavanKalyan I have eddited it, I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Aside: I know **eval is evil**. The user could do by this certain injections. This is only one possibility to do this there are certain other ways*.

I just added before "output =", cut from the input-string the "doSomething(" and the last ")". By this I have a normal command-line which I could execute by eval.

I highly **not recommend** to use eval this way; especially you don't
know what the user will do, so you don't know what could all happen
with your code and data.

```js
let form = {first_name: 'Mickey', family_name: 'Mouse'};
let timeStart = (new Date()).toString();

let input = `doSomething({
  type: 'type',
  Unit: 'unit',
  attributes: [
    {
      attribute: 'attribute',
      value: form.first_name
    },
    {
      attribute: 'attribute2',
      value: form.family_name
    }
  ],
  groups: [
    {
      smth: 'string1',
      smth2: 'string2',
      start: timeStart.substring(0, 9)
    }
  ]
})`;
let pos= "doSomething(".length;
input = 'output = ' + input.substr(pos, input.length-pos-1);
eval(input);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you, that does work. I will wait a little to see if something without eval comes up as it is highly discouraged to use but if not I will mark yours as the solution, because I cannot come up with something better. Thanks again for putting the effort:)